# How to convert a fractional binary to decimal fraction in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, binary, decimal

I am looking for a way to convert a fractional binary part to decimal fraction in Swift 3. This code converts binary Integer to decimal

```
for num in BinaryIntegerPart {

        switch num {

        case "0": result = result * 2
        case "1": result = result * 2 + 1
            print (result)
        default: return "Error"    
}
```

Maybe there is same workaround but only for fractional part?

For example:
101.0101 to 5.3125 (decimal)

Comment: Can you reedit question? It's hard to get what exactly do you want from the current post.

Comment: So you want for example convert "101.01" to 5.25 ?

Comment: User28434, okay

Comment: Martin, yeah exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as the decimal point is encountered you have to switch
to adding powers of 1/2 to the result:

```
func fractionalBinaryToDecimal(bin: String) -> Double? {
    var result = 0.0
    var inFractionalPart = false // Set to `true` if the decimal point is encountered
    var fractionalValue = 1.0 // Current power of 1/2 when adding the fractional part

    for digit in bin.characters { // Swift 4: for digit in bin { ...
        switch digit {
        case "0":
            if inFractionalPart {
                fractionalValue /= 2.0
            } else {
                result = 2 * result
            }
        case "1":
            if inFractionalPart {
                fractionalValue /= 2.0
                result += fractionalValue
            } else {
                result = 2 * result + 1
            }
        case ".":
            guard !inFractionalPart else { return nil } // Repeated decimal point
            inFractionalPart = true
        default:
            return nil // Invalid digit
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Example:

```
if let val = fractionalBinaryToDecimal(bin: "101.0101") {
    print(val) // 5.3125
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!